# Compare 3 pairs of XML files using Windows Batch

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a batch file which reads 3 pair of identical XML files stored in two different locations and compares whether their build versions are same or not using different tags like build tag & minor tag in the xml files.

I have 3 XML files, master.xml,TGDD.xml and TMasterData.xml.I have stored these 3 xml files in 2 different locations and want to check whether their versions are same or not in these two locations.

Batch code is..

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "build=" 
set "build1="

set "gddbuild="
set "gddbuild1="

set "tbuild="
set "tbuild1="


set "ans=Master_Data version same"
set "wrong=Master_Data version not same"

set "ans1=TGDD version same"
set "wrong1=TGDD version not same"

set "ans2=TMasterData version same"
set "wrong2=TMasterData version not same"


for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%a in ('
    2^>nul type "C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\piller-uniblock\master.xml"
                "C:\piller-uniblock\master.xml"
    ^| find /i "<Build>" 
') do if not defined build ( set "build=%%a" ) else ( set "build1=%%a" )

IF "%build%"=="%build1%" ( echo %ans% ) else echo %wrong%

for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%b in ('
    2^>nul type "C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\piller-uniblock\TGDD.xml"
                "C:\piller-uniblock\TGDD.xml"
    ^| find /i "<Minor>" 
') do if not defined gddbuild ( set "gddbuild=%%b" ) else ( set "gddbuild1=%%b" )

IF "%gddbuild%"=="%gddbuild1%" ( echo %ans1% ) else echo %wrong1%


for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%c in ('
    2^>nul type "C:\Users\Lucy\Desktop\piller-uniblock\TMasterData.xml"
                "C:\piller-uniblock\TMasterData.xml"
    ^| find /i "<Build>" 
') do if not defined tbuild ( set "tbuild=%%c" ) else ( set "tbuild1=%%c" )

IF "%tbuild%"=="%tbuild1%" ( echo %ans2% ) else echo %wrong2%
```

The output..

[image: output]

Even though the above code is running properly in the command prompt, I can't seem to understand how to make the above code more effcient i.e without using 3 for loops.Please Help...

The code for the 3 XML files are...

master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CDMDataXML xmlns="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema CDMLoaderXMLSchema.xsd">
<CDMDataVersion>
<Major>1</Major>
<Minor>0</Minor>
<Build>50</Build>
<Delimiter>.</Delimiter>
</CDMDataVersion>
```

TGDD.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TrellisGdd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <TrellisVersion>
 <VersionId>1</VersionId>
 <Major>3</Major>
 <Delimiter>.</Delimiter>
 <Minor>32</Minor>
 <LastDictionaryEntry>3806</LastDictionaryEntry>
 </TrellisVersion>
```

TMasterData.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CDMDataXML xmlns="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema CDMLoaderXMLSchema.xsd">
 <CDMDataVersion>
    <Major>3</Major>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
    <Build>15</Build>
    <Delimiter>.</Delimiter>
 </CDMDataVersion>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File names/paths shortened to better see the call, change to full file paths.

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :compareXML "master.xml" "master1.xml" "Major, Minor, Build" 
    if errorlevel 1 ( echo different ) else ( echo match )

    call :compareXML "TGDD.xml" "TGDD1.xml" "VersionID, Major, Minor" 
    if errorlevel 1 ( echo different ) else ( echo match )

    call :compareXML "TMasterData.xml" "TMasterData1.xml" "Major, Minor, Build" 
    if errorlevel 1 ( echo different ) else ( echo match )

    exit /b

:compareXML file1 file2 taglist
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "match=" & for %%a in (%~3) do set "match=!match! /c:"^<%%a^>""
    endlocal & set match=%match%

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=<> " %%a in ('
        type "%~1" "%~2" 2^> nul ^| findstr /i /l %match%
    ') do if not defined _F1_%%a ( set "_F1_%%a=%%b" ) else (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%c in ("!_F1_%%a!.") do (
            endlocal 
            if /i not "%%b."=="%%~c" ( endlocal & exit /b 1 ) 
            set "_F1_%%a="
        )
    )
    set _F1_ 2>nul && ( endlocal & exit /b 1 ) || ( endlocal & exit /b 0 )
```

As the operation needs to be performed for each pair of files, the code has been moved to a subroutine. This subroutine is called with the full path for each file and the list of the tags to be compared.

Both files are typed, and as the tags are found, environment variables are set for the first file and compared agains the previous value for the second file. If all match, the files have the same values, if something does not match or at the end the number or tags do not match (variables are removed as matches are found, if  something remains it is a no match) files are different.

Comment: How will i display custom messages for each pair of XML files like I have shown in the output screen-shot using your logic??

Comment: @Lucy, after each `call :compareXML` you will get an `errorlevel 1` if the files does not match or a `errorlevel 0` if the files match. Just change the `echo` commands in the sample code to your needs.