# Compare Multiple tags of XML files using Windows Batch

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a Batch file which compares two copies of a single XML file stored at two different locations and checks whether their versions are same or not.

Currently I'm using fc & findstr command to check only the build tag in the 2 files but i want to add the functionality in which the code 1st checks the major tag, if it is different then the code stops executing and prints "files different".

If the values are same then it proceeds to checking the minor tags in the 2 files.if the values are different then the code stops executing and prints "files different". if values are same then it proceeds to checking the build tag.If the build values are different then it prints "Files different" else "files same"..

So the flow of checking tags is  ->  ->

The file stored at 2 different locations is

TData.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CDMDataXML xmlns="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.avocent.org/trellis/CDMLoaderXMLSchema CDMLoaderXMLSchema.xsd">
<CDMDataVersion>
    <Major>3</Major>
    <Minor>0</Minor>
    <Build>19</Build>
    <Delimiter>.</Delimiter>
</CDMDataVersion>
```

The batch code I'm using is..

```
    @echo off
  fc D:\SVN\TData\TData.xml Z:\TDataGDDFolders\TData.xml /A > nul

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo.
    echo in SVN
    findstr "<Build>" D:\SVN\TData\TData.xml
    echo.
    echo  in DropBox
    findstr "<Build>" Z:\TDataGDDFolders\TData.xml
    echo.
    echo.
    echo TData files are different.
) else (
    echo.
    echo in SVN
    findstr "<Build>" D:\SVN\TData\TData.xml
    echo.
    echo  in DropBox
    findstr "<Build>" Z:\TDataGDDFolders\TData.xml
    echo.
    echo.
    echo TData files matches.    
)
```

I'm trying to add the above mentioned functionality in the batch code but can't seem to understand how to do it...Please Help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reuse the code from [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25912566/2861476)

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file1=%cd%\tdata_1.xml"
    set "file2=%cd%\tdata_2.xml"

    call :compareXML "%file1%" "%file2%" "Major" || ( echo files different & goto :eof )
    call :compareXML "%file1%" "%file2%" "Minor" || ( echo files different & goto :eof )
    call :compareXML "%file1%" "%file2%" "Build" || ( echo files different & goto :eof )

    echo files same

    exit /b

:compareXML file1 file2 taglist
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    set "match=" & for %%a in (%~3) do set "match=!match! /c:"^<%%a^>""
    endlocal & set match=%match%

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=<> " %%a in ('
        type "%~1" "%~2" 2^> nul ^| findstr /i /l %match%
    ') do if not defined _F1_%%a ( set "_F1_%%a=%%b" ) else (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%c in ("!_F1_%%a!.") do (
            endlocal 
            if /i not "%%b."=="%%~c" ( endlocal & exit /b 1 ) 
            set "_F1_%%a="
        )
    )
    set _F1_ 2>nul && ( endlocal & exit /b 1 ) || ( endlocal & exit /b 0 )
```

Comment: If i want to add the complete path like "D:\SVN\TData\TData.xml" should i add it inside %cd% or outside it??

Comment: @Lucy, in place of `%cd%`. Directly use `"set file1=D:\SVN\TData\TData.xml"`. It was included simply to show that the file references can include a path (the current directory in the sample)